# CSS Grid System for Forms (with Inline Labels)

Tags: javascript, css, forms

This is a [**follow up to this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1775532/css-grid-system-for-forms-multi-column), I'm trying to have the same multi-column format but with inline labels instead of block labels, take the following mockup for instance:

[image: mockup with inline labels]

It's not very clear in the image but the `name (label)` + `name (input)` should occupy 50% (or near that) of the container width, the same goes for the `email label + input`, while the `country (label)` + `country (select)` should occupy 100% of the width.

I would like to have the same HTML / CSS used in the question mentioned above and change the appearance of the form by stylizing label elements with a class `inlineLabel` or `blockLabel`.

Is this possible?

**PS: I'm sorry for being such a pain in the ass but form UIs is probably the most complex and important aspect of a web application one should care about, the whole set of form elements is also one of the most complex to stylize and I would like to put a end to this headache by creating a simple CSS "framework" to stylize forms in a simple manner.**

Comment: Classnames such as `inlineX` or `blockX` is just as (un-) maintainable as using inline styling.

Comment: If the grid system is designed correctly, you would have grids defined that would allow you to grid within the grid, in your case use 50% of the parent container.

Comment: @chelmertz: I just used the `X` to make my point more explicit. =)

Comment: @Kevin: I'm sorry, but I'm not following what you mean. =\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not subdivide you column into two columns for the Name and Email, use a reset div, then use 100% for the country select (assumes Grid960):

```
<div class="grid_10">
  <div class="alpha grid_5">
    Name <input id="Name" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="omega grid_5">
    Email<input id="Name" type="text"/>
  </div>
  <div class="clear"/>
</div>
<div class="clear"/>
<div class="grid_10">

</div>
```

Comment: Using 960 you would need to use alpha (on div1) and omega (on div2) on the inner divs (or both on the containing div). Otherwise your inner divs will overflow

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it later on. BTW you mean 960.gs, but the fluid or the fixed one?

Comment: @Kevin: Thanks for your input, I **think** it should work with the fluid grid.

Comment: I have not tried the fluid version out yet. It is possible that they have fixed these sorts of issues that plague the fixed version.

Comment: @Kevin Peno - yikes!! Fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. Are you looking for someone to code this up for you or just looking for some general direction? One way you could do it is float your labels to the left with some defined width. Your input boxes could then be floated right (or left) with some width (ie. 50%). The widths need to be defined in such a way that both can exist on the same level without overlapping (ie. add up to <= 100% of the space you have available).

Name and Email should exist in two columns, but the country and message line should not be as they extend through what you are defining as columns.

Comment: A general direction might be enough, I'm not a CSS master though. But I'll set up a bounty as soon as I can if I'm unable to reach a solution by my own. I'll try your solution later on (I'm in a hurry right now) and I'll let you know how it went. Thanks for your input! +1