# Problems with Forms and CSS

Tags: css, forms, webforms

This is a **[follow up to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1949312/css-grid-system-for-forms-with-inline-labels)**. I've tried to come up with a solution that allowed me to have in-line labels in a multi-column form, by reading some of the answers provided in the question mentioned above I realized that it was much more simpler than I originally had though, this is my prototype:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
._20 {
    width: 16%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
._30 {
    width: 26%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
label {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="_20">
            <p><label>Name:</label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
            <p><input type="text" id="" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_20">
            <p><label>Email:</label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
            <p><input type="text" id="" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

In theory this seems to work, but in practice all I get is this very weird result (in FF 3.5.6):

[image: weird result screenshot]

If I drop the `p` tags around the labels and input the result changes a bit:

[image: weird result without p tags screenshot]

**What's wrong? Is there any hack I'm supposed to make use of?**

**How can I place the labels / inputs inside the box like they are supposed to?**

I appreciate all input, thanks.

Comment: Why are you using paragraph tags for form fields?

Comment: @NSD: I based myself on the fluid960 grid system that also uses `p` tags on form fields, I've update the question now though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
._20 {
    width: 16%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
._30 {
    width: 26%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
label {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 10px 0px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    padding: 10px;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
   overflow:hidden;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="_20">
                <p><label>Name:</label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
                <p><input type="text" id="" /></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_20">
                <p><label>Email:</label></p>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
                <p><input type="text" id="" /></p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

BTW, Check this out: [How to create perfect form Markup and style it with CSS](http://fecklessmind.com/2009/01/23/how-to-reliable-css-forms/)

Comment: =) Thanks Nimbuz, both for the solution and for the link. You've been very helpful.

Comment: np :) Make sure you add width to content if you want to support IE6 as well.

Comment: Just apply width:100% to .content and you should be fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one. The main thing is the clear:both; div at the bottom, but there are a few more things changed too.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<style>
._20 {
    width: 16%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
._30 {
    width: 26%;
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 2%;
    margin-right: 2%;
}
label {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
input {
    border: 1px solid #B3B3B3;
    font-family: inherit;
    padding: 3px;
    width: 100%;
}
.box {
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #666;
}
.content {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    -moz-border-radius: 6px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <div class="_20">
                <label>Name:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
                <input type="text" id="" />
        </div>
        <div class="_20">
                <label>Email:</label>
        </div>
        <div class="_30">
                <input type="text" id="" />
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"></div>
    </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

first of all you need to reset the padding and margins on the `<p>` elements

```
p,label{ 
 padding:0; 
 margin:0 
}
```

secondly, you are floating elements inside a block element without clearing them later... hence the overflow issue... here is a working version of the code http://jsbin.com/eheva3

**Note:** I have used the `clearit` method which requires extra markup
You can use either that or the "clearfix" method... google for "clearfix" to find out more

Answer (score 0):

You should start with the simplest possible implementation that works and build whatever fancy styling you want up from there. Getting rid of all the extraneous tags, all you really need is:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="content">
        <label>Name:</label>
        <input type="text" />
    </div>
</div>
```

You don't need to add more divs and paragraphs to get it to snap to a grid, just style the elements that are already there.